# using PHP to get information in xml file. How to make it shorter and expandable in the future?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

These are the working codes that i have done. the program is about accessing information in an xml file such as student's name,id and marks based on group and team number submitted from a form. there are 2 submit buttons if one button is clicked, it will display with an additional element (pic) and the other one without it. so far so good.

but looking at the php codes, i know that i will be facing problems if there are numerous groups and team numbers. there would be a lot of if-else statements and the codes would be very long. i have tried using foreach but i'm not getting the result that i want. are there anyways to simplify this? i have been searching on the web but it seems that i just don't know how to implement them. quite new to this.

```
<html><style>
    .datagrid table { border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center; width: 100%; }
    .datagrid {font: normal 12px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
               background: #fff; 
               overflow: hidden; 
               border: 4px solid #006699; 
               -webkit-border-radius: 20px; 
               -moz-border-radius: 20px; 
               border-radius: 20px; }
    .datagrid table td, .datagrid table th { padding: 7px 20px; }
    .datagrid table thead th {background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #006699), color-stop(1, #00557F) );
                              background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #006699 5%, #00557F 100% ); filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#006699', endColorstr='#00557F');
                              background-color:#006699; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold;
                              border-left: 1px solid #0070A8; } 
    .datagrid table thead th:first-child { border: none; }
    .datagrid table tbody td { color: #00496B; border-left: 1px solid #E1EEF4;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal; }
    .datagrid table tbody .alt td { background: #E1EEF4; color: #00496B; }
    .datagrid table tbody td:first-child { border-left: none; }
    .datagrid table tbody tr:last-child td { border-bottom: none; }
</style>
<center>
<form action="" method="post" >
    <select name="group">
        <option value="csa">CSA</option>
        <option value="csb">CSB</option>
    </select>

    Enter team number:<input type="text" name="teamnum" value="">

    <input type="submit" name="submit1"  value="With Photo">
    <input type="submit" name="submit2"  value="Without Photo">
</form>
<form action="index.php">
    <input type="submit" value="main">
</form>
</center>
</html>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit1']) != '') {

$file = "student.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file) or die("Unable to load XML file!");
if (isset($_POST['group']) && isset($_POST['teamnum']) != '') {
    $teamnum = $_POST['teamnum'];
    $group = $_POST['group'];

    if ($group == 'csa' && $teamnum == '1') {
        $name = $xml->xpath('//student[teamNum[contains(text(),"1")] and group[contains(text(),"CSA")]]/name');
        $id = $xml->xpath('//student[teamNum[contains(text(),"1")] and group[contains(text(),"CSA")]]/id');
        $total = $xml->xpath('//student[teamNum[contains(text(),"1")] and group[contains(text(),"CSA")]]/total');
        //$photo =$xml->xpath('//student[teamNum[contains(text(),"1")] and group[contains(text(),"CSA")]]/pic');

        echo "<div class='datagrid'><table border='1' cellpadding='1'>";
        echo "<thead><tr><th>Photo</th><th>Name</th><th>ID</th><th>carry marks</th></tr></thead>";
        while ((list(, $node) = each($name)) && (list(, $node1) = each($id)) && (list(, $node2) = each($total))) {
            echo "<tbody><tr class='alt'>";
            echo "<td>1</td>";
            echo "<td>$node</td>";
            echo "<td>$node1</td>";
            echo "<td>$node2</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody></table></div>";
    }
    else if ($group == 'csa' && $teamnum == '2') {
        $name = $xml->xpath('//student[teamNum[contains(text(),"2")] and group[contains(text(),"CSA")]]/name');
        $id = $xml->xpath('//student[teamNum[contains(text(),"2")] and group[contains(text(),"CSA")]]/id');
        $total = $xml->xpath('//student[teamNum[contains(text(),"2")] and group[contains(text(),"CSA")]]/total');
        //$photo =$xml->xpath('//student[teamNum[contains(text(),"2")] and group[contains(text(),"CSA")]]/pic');

        echo "<div class='datagrid'><table border='1' cellpadding='1'>";
        echo "<thead><tr><th>Photo</th><th>Name</th><th>ID</th><th>carry marks</th></tr></thead>";
        while ((list(, $node) = each($name)) && (list(, $node1) = each($id)) && (list(, $node2) = each($total))) {
            echo "<tbody><tr class='alt'>";
            echo "<td>1</td>";
            echo "<td>$node</td>";
            echo "<td>$node1</td>";
            echo "<td>$node2</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody></table></div>";
    }
else if (isset($_POST['submit2']) != '') {

$file = "student.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file) or die("Unable to load XML file!");
if (isset($_POST['group']) && isset($_POST['teamnum']) != '') {
    $teamnum = $_POST['teamnum'];
    $group = $_POST['group'];
    if ($group == 'csa' && $teamnum == '1') {
        $name = $xml->xpath('//student[teamNum[contains(text(),"1")] and group[contains(text(),"CSA")]]/name');
        $id = $xml->xpath('//student[teamNum[contains(text(),"1")] and group[contains(text(),"CSA")]]/id');
        $total = $xml->xpath('//student[teamNum[contains(text(),"1")] and group[contains(text(),"CSA")]]/total');

        echo "<div class='datagrid'><table border='1' cellpadding='1'>";
        echo "<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>ID</th><th>carry marks</th></tr></thead>";
        while ((list(, $node) = each($name)) && (list(, $node1) = each($id)) && (list(, $node2) = each($total))) {
            echo "<tbody><tr class='alt'>";
            echo "<td>$node</td>";
            echo "<td>$node1</td>";
            echo "<td>$node2</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody></table></div>";
    }
    else if ($group == 'csa' && $teamnum == '2') {
        $name = $xml->xpath('//student[teamNum[contains(text(),"2")] and group[contains(text(),"CSA")]]/name');
        $id = $xml->xpath('//student[teamNum[contains(text(),"2")] and group[contains(text(),"CSA")]]/id');
        $total = $xml->xpath('//student[teamNum[contains(text(),"2")] and group[contains(text(),"CSA")]]/total');

        echo "<div class='datagrid'><table border='1' cellpadding='1'>";
        echo "<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>ID</th><th>carry marks</th></tr></thead>";
        while ((list(, $node) = each($name)) && (list(, $node1) = each($id)) && (list(, $node2)= each($total))) {
            echo "<tbody><tr class='alt'>";
            echo "<td>$node</td>";
            echo "<td>$node1</td>";
            echo "<td>$node2</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody></table></div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please read the [FAQ] and how to post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). Posting a question like this would require to post valid code (do not cut closing brackets), input data, expected output and actual output/the exact error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the way to solve this by using foreach

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit1']) != '') {

$file = "student.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file) or die("Unable to load XML file!");
if (isset($_POST['group']) && isset($_POST['teamnum']) != '') {
    $teamnum = $_POST['teamnum'];
    $group = $_POST['group'];

    echo "<div class='datagrid'><table border='1' cellpadding='1'>";
    echo "<thead><tr><th>Photo</th><th>Name</th><th>ID</th><th>carry marks</th></tr></thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    foreach ($xml->xpath("//student[contains(teamNum, $teamnum) and contains(group, $group)]") as $student) {

        echo "<tr class='alt'>";  
        echo "<td>".$student->picture."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$student->name."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$student->id."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$student->total."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    } 
echo "</tbody></table></div>";
    }else            echo 'no data';

} else {
    echo "enter a team's number";    
}

?>
```

the trick is in the xpath. it selects all students that contains submitted values. after that it will be as $student and i will be able to output the element values from there.